# Not able to find public , src, .gitignore on my react app on mac

Tags: reactjs

I have created the react app by using the  "npx create-react-app filename ", on mac terminal after this when i opened the file using vs code it it didn't had the files i.e, .gitignore,public and src what could be the reason , I have followed all the steps very carefully installing the latest version of node etc.

Comment: add screenshots or something

Comment: whitch version of npm you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed `create-react-app` globally . you should uninstall it  using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` .  then run `npx create-react-app my-app`